# Hanging floating shelving

Tags: woodworking, shelving

I am making similar shelving to these and I am trying to figure out the best method to hang these shelving. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An option would be a keyhole bracket mortised into each side of the shelf.  Add screws with drywall anchors and hang.

[image: Keyhole bracket]

Answer (score 1):

Pins that are fixed into the wall that have matching holes on the shelves.

You can then have combinations of holes to adjust height and if you are creative you can achieve angles as well...

I would use steel pins and you can get them with a  hex or flat slot or just glue steel rod into place.

I had to mount an oak beam and made 3 steel pins 1/2” diameter 12” long - glued up and that beam is solid (a 6” by 8” 5 foot beam...)